# Hiding the API key in the Python file while doing a sentiment analysis

Tags: python, azure

I am a beginner in Python. I am using text-analytics to do sentiment analysis using the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/text-analytics/quickstarts/text-analytics-sdk?tabs=version-3-1&pivots=programming-language-python

But I want to hide the API key. I have created a .env file where I saved the API key. How should I write the python programme.

Note: If I write the program with API key visible it is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you'll want to load your `.env` file as environment variables in your OS. On Linux, this would be the `source` command. This will then allow you to use python's `os` library to retrieve the environment variable, specifically the `getenv()` method.

e.g.

**`.env`** written as follows:

```
FOO=bar
```

**`read_env.py`** written as follows:

```py
from os import getenv

foo = getenv('FOO')
print(foo)
```

Then you can run them in your os.

```sh
$ source .env
$ python read_env.py
bar
```

More info can be found at https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getenv

Comment: The MacOS Terminal uses a linux variant. These commands will work there, too.

Comment: Thanks. Another question. If I hide the API key in a txt file. What command should I put in the python program without disclosing  the contents of txt file.

Comment: @ Beex Something is wrong in the file. It is not running. May be I am not choosing the right path.